# I cant seem to be able to add a document to a collection in Robo 3T

Tags: javascript, mongodb

When I right click a collection, it doesn't show any way to add a document when videos usually have it. Does anyone know if they changed the way to do it for newer versions? CTRL-D doesn't seem to work either. It just shows:

intellishell, export collection, import data, copy name |
rename, duplicate, clear, and delete coll |
add index, add/edit validate, |
collection statistics, server info |
refresh and refresh all

It doesnt seem to have show any way to view the contents.
I would show a picture but it isn't allowed yet. thank you!